# OS X batch convert a folder flv files to .mp4 files using ffmpeg don't work

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a service with automator tha converts flv contained in a folder in mp4 changing container only.

Reading other questions here I've used this shell

```
for f in .flv
do
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.5/bin/ffmpeg -i “$f” -c copy "${f%.*}.mp4"
done
```

but when trying out the service I keep receving an error message "shell script action found an error"

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:

- Replace `.flv` with `*.flv`.
- Replace `“$f”` with `"$f"`.

You can find shell script issues with [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: I've corrected like this
    
for f in *.flv
    do
    /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.5/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy "${f%.*}.mp4"
    done

But I'm still getting the error...

Comment: @kiltro You need to edit your question and add your updated command/script and provide the complete console output. Also provide the output of the command `echo $SHELL`.